# Different text size for different hardwares

Tags: android, android-layout

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/entry"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
    android:textColor="#800080"
    android:text=""
    android:hint=" No Operator Precednce yet"
    android:cursorVisible="false" 
    android:textSize="40dip"

     />
```

I want the above layout for hardware with size more than 4 inch. and for lesser one i want remove the last line android:textSize="40dip".. How can i achieve this ?